# Why BeautifulSoup misses <p> tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup, the findAll method is missing `<p>` tags. I run the code and it returns and empty list. But if I inspect the page I can clearly see it as shown in the picture bellow.

I chose some random site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#An example web site
url = 'https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-extract-text-from-an-html-file-in-python'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.findAll("p"))
```

The output:

```
(env) pinux@main:~/dev$ python trial.py
[]
```

I inspect the page using the browser:

[image]

The text is clearly there. Why doesn't BeautifulSoup catch them? Can someone shed some light on what is going on?

Comment: Probably because they’re generated by JavaScript.

Comment: Use `View Source` to see if they're in the HTML or were added dynamically by JavaScript.

Comment: Looking at the source, it definitely is JS rendered. If the website has no SSR, then bs4 won't work. You'll need to use tools like Cypress, Selenium, etc. that can run JS and capture the source/navigate it.

Comment: The data gets pulled dynamically from here: https://docsapi.kite.com/api/python/answers/how-to-extract-text-from-an-html-file-in-python

Comment: Thanks friends. Feels like back to square one but lets get this JavaScript rendered text. I was so confused. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that parts of this webpage is rendered in JavaScript. You can try using `selenium`, since Selenium WebDrivers automatically wait for the page to fully render.

```py
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://url-to-webpage.com")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am using Selenium now. I was so confused! now I get it.